# How to select next record and previous record in SQLite?

Tags: java, sql, database, sqlite

I have been searching like forever

I am using min and max for the last and and first record but how do I get the next/ record? I have a column name rowid it is the pk and auto incremented by one every time a user registers

| rowid | Name |
|  1    | John |*
|  2    | Mark |
|  3    | Peter|
|  4    | Help |

so if I click the next button I wanted to select mark which is in rowid 2

| rowid | Name |
|  1    | John |
|  2    | Mark |*
|  3    | Peter|
|  4    | Help |

but if I click the next button twice I want to be in rowid 4

| rowid | Name |
|  1    | John |
|  2    | Mark |
|  3    | Peter|
|  4    | Help |*

how do I do that? by the way I don't have fixed rows since I have a registration function

so here's my code

```
    JButton btnNextLast = new JButton(">>");
    btnNextLast.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            try{
                String sQuery = "select * from accountinfo where rowid =  (SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM accountinfo)";
                PreparedStatement prst = connection.prepareStatement(sQuery);
                ResultSet rs = prst.executeQuery();
                lblSID.setText(rs.getString("sid"));
                lblfirst.setText(rs.getString("last"));
                lblLast.setText(rs.getString("first"));
                lblmiddle.setText(rs.getString("middle"));
                lblbirth.setText(rs.getString("birth"));
                lblcontact.setText(rs.getString("contact"));

            }catch(Exception qwe){

            }



        }
    });
```

I've tried

```
select rowid
from accountinfo
where rowid >1
order by rowid
limit 1
```

but no luck

and if I remove order by rowid limit 1. It just show the next record which is 2 and never function again

Comment: anyone? :( 

can't really find a solution for this :((

Comment: Your problem wulod be easy if it was another RDBMs but unfortunately SQLite doesn't help! I'm afraid that you have to do it on your java code. I would recomend a LinkedList where you can simulate your requirement. Walking though the registries.

Comment: Another sugestion for you is since you increment always by 1 your rowId you can store it on a variable and when a user click on next button you sum the id that was clicked with one. So if a user clicks twice it will sum twice. And with this new Id you can simple do your select as: `select * from accountinfo where rowid = ?`passing the value that was summed as parameter.

Comment: The query you've shown is correct (if you replace `1` with whatever the last rowid was). What do you think is wrong with it?